# servletの文字化けについての質問です。

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, tomcat, servlet

sevletについて勉強しているものです。
今は練習中テストアプリを作成しているのですが、
UTF-8を指定してるのに、文字化けに遭いました。

開発環境は
OS : fedora28
JDK : java10
tomcat : 9.0.11
eclipse : 4.8

```
package studyDOGET;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class New_doGet
 */
@WebServlet("/New_doGet")
public class New_doGet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public New_doGet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println(createHTML("GET"));

    out.close();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println(createHTML("POST"));
    out.close();

}

private String createHTML(String methodType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    sBuffer.append("<html>");
    sBuffer.append("<head>");
    sBuffer.append("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
    sBuffer.append("<title>サンプル</title>");
    sBuffer.append("</head>");

    sBuffer.append("<p>");
    sBuffer.append(methodType);
    sBuffer.append("メソッドで呼び出されました</p>");
    sBuffer.append("<p><a href=\" Sample1\">リンク</a></p>");
    sBuffer.append("<form action=\" Sample1\" method=\"get\">");
    sBuffer.append("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"GETで送信\">");
    sBuffer.append("</form>");

    sBuffer.append("<form action=\" Sample1\" method=\"post\">");
    sBuffer.append("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"POSTで送信\">");
    sBuffer.append("</form>");

    sBuffer.append("</body>");
    sBuffer.append("</html>");

    return (new String(sBuffer));
    }

}
```

web.xml ：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
<display-name>ERP</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/helloworld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

printout結果：

[image: 文字化け]

eclipseの設定画面:

[image: eclipse]

google先生にききましたが、UTF-8のタグなども追加してみました。
効きませんでした。
ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`doGet()` 内で、`getWriter()` よりも前に `setContentType()` を呼ぶ必要があります。

現在のコード:

```
response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

修正案:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
```

Comment: すごい！はやいです！解決できました！ありがとうございました！